# Assigning useRef through render props

Tags: reactjs

Using Render props pattern I wanted to see if there was a way to make this work using the current setup. I have a Parent component that uses an Example component as a wrapper to render some children inside it. I wanted to pass off a ref from inside of Example to one of the children in the render prop. Is this possible ?

```
const Example = ({ children }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [open, SetOpen] = useState(false);
  const [controls] = useCustomAnimation(open, ref);

  return (
    <div>
      {children({ ref })}
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Example>
        {ref => {
          <motion.div
            ref={ref}
          >
           {console.log('ref= ', ref)}
          ....... more children
          </motion.div>;
        }}
       </Example>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: How do you expect to assign single ref to multiple children?

Comment: Why not just make the ref inside `Parent`, as pass it as a normal prop to `Example`?

Comment: Seems ok to me. What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: Dennis is it on a single child not multiple. See code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your current file is almost exactly correct.  I setup an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-bush-3uv3u?file=/src/App.js), but here is the gist:

```
const Example = ({ children }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  return <div>{children({ ref })}</div>;
};

const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Example>
        {({ ref }) => {
          console.log(ref);
          return <input type="text" ref={ref} />;
        }}
      </Example>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Note: You need to destructure the object you are passing into the `children` function.

Comment: Thanks jack. I noticed in your code you had to return the jsx. Way do you have to add the second return inside the render ? Is this so Example knows what JSX to put the ref on.

Comment: You need to return _something_ that can be rendered in your JSX, even if the child is a function.  It can be any node, but it needs to be renderable.  You can simplify it to just `({ref}) => <input type="text" ref="ref" />` without the `return`, but that is just syntactic sugar (the return is implicit).  Not sure if that answers your question, but there you go. :)  Good luck!